# Error when deploying site of a maven multi module project with FTP

Tags: java, maven, ftp, javadoc, website-deployment

I have a multi module project. When I launch `mvn site:deploy`, the deployment of the base module works fine, but it fails to create the directory of the module sites on the FTP server:

```
[INFO] Error uploading site
Embedded error: Required directory: '/myremoteftprepository/myproject-mymodule' is missing
```

When I create the missing directory by hand, it works fine, but I would like to avoid that. It is surprising that the deploy command do not create it. Do you how to force this directory creation? Is it a bug in the wagon-ftp plugin?

FYI, here is my POM:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

I have chosen to include the javadoc with:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <!-- include javadoc in the site -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <show>public</show>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

and

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>site</id>
        <name>maven site</name>
        <url>ftp://ftp.blabla.org/myremoteftprepository</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

and my settings.xml is good.

Comment: exactly the same problem. Did you solve this issue on your own?

Comment: NO! And I am still looking for the solution.

Comment: uhm.. ok .. :( The strange thing is that the snapshot and release deploy works great. This is only a site problem

Comment: Maybe give it a try with the most recent version (2.2) of wagon-ftp?

Comment: Behe, thanks for your hint: It works with the new version! If you change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the most recent version of wagon-ftp (2.2), it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should not launch the site:deploy goal, but rather the site-deploy Maven lifecycle phase e.g. like that

```
mvn clean install site-deploy
```

and also make sure that [the latest version of your wagon transport is used](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.maven.wagon%22%20AND%20a%3a%22wagon-ftp%22) (2.2).

Also for javadoc plugin you should configure it as reporting plugin under the configuration of the maven site plugin.